# Wordpress setup for WAMP local environment

Tags: php, wordpress

I have downloaded a word press site I need to work on the front-end. The problem I am having it that every page apart from the homepage displays my root server /index.php

Since downloading I have:

1. Updated the wp_options for both siteurl and home
2. Updated the rewritebase in .htaccess url to the name of the subfolder.

Is there anything else I need to update?

The admin area fully works correctly just every page/post apart from homepage

EDIT: Add .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

END2 - Fixed by removing a /

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Sadly no this has made no difference.

Comment: What happens if you type in index.php i.e. http://localhost/wordpress/index.php - does that still take you back to your root ?

Comment: No it direct me to: localhost/wordpress/

Comment: A little extra debugging and it defiantly looks like a problem in the .htaccess file. Added contents to answer above

Comment: Strange, within wp-admin settings - reading, do you have a static home page setup ? If so you may need to reassign that and save ... ?

Comment: Yes the front page display is set to a static page

Comment: Just amended my answer need to include the wordpress part in the bottom line. ?

Comment: Thank you Shane, all the CMS/Ecommerce store I have worked with I only ever need to update the rewritebase Check my EDIT 2 that also works.